# How to index a numpy array with another numpy array in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I am trying to index an np.array with another array so that I can have zeros everywhere after a certain index but it gives me the error

> TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar
> index

Basically what I would like my code to do is that if I have:

```py
a = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]])
d = np.array([2, 1, 3])
```

that I could do something like

```py
a[d:] = 0
```

to give the output

```
a = [[ 1  2  3]
     [ 4  0  6]
     [ 0  0  9]
     [ 0  0  0]]
```

Comment: In the `d:` expression, `d` has to be a scalar, a single value, not an array!

Comment: yes I know but I was hoping I could do something with an array as I have more than one value I want to use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A widely used approach for this kind of problem is to construct a boolean mask, comparing the index array with the appropriate `arange`:

```
In [619]: mask = np.arange(4)[:,None]>=d
In [620]: mask
Out[620]: 
array([[False, False, False],
       [False,  True, False],
       [ True,  True, False],
       [ True,  True,  True]])
In [621]: a[mask]
Out[621]: array([ 5,  7,  8, 10, 11, 12])
In [622]: a[mask] = 0
In [623]: a
Out[623]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 0, 6],
       [0, 0, 9],
       [0, 0, 0]])
```

That's not necessarily faster than a row (or in this case column) iteration. Since slicing is basic indexing, it may be faster, even if done several times.

```
In [624]: for i,v in enumerate(d):
     ...:     print(a[v:,i])
     ...: 
[0 0]
[0 0 0]
[0]
```

Generally if a result involves multiple arrays or lists with different lengths, there isn't a "neat" multidimensional solution.  Either iterate over those lists, or step back and "think outside the box".

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with array indexing but it doesn't feel natural.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]])
d = np.array([2, 1, 3])

col_ix = [ 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2 ]  # column ix for each item to change                                   
row_ix = [ 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 3 ]  # row index for each item to change

a[ row_ix, col_ix ] = 0

a 
# array([[1, 2, 3],
#        [4, 0, 6],
#        [0, 0, 9],
#        [0, 0, 0]])
```

With a for loop

```
a = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]])

for ix_col, ix_row in enumerate( d ):  # iterate across the columns
    a[ ix_row:, ix_col ] = 0

a 
# array([[1, 2, 3],
#        [4, 0, 6],
#        [0, 0, 9],
#        [0, 0, 0]])
```

Comment: yes you're right it doesn't feel natural I think I should take a different approach at what I'm trying to attempt. I have a more complex array I am trying to apply my thoughts here to so if it doesn't work for a small array I've no chance with a larger!